# CSS image gets distorted when removing border

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to CSS and I'm doing the 100 days of code challenge to get better and faster. I've run into a problem when I try to remove the border from an image.

The border is positioned as relative and the rest of the elements are positioned as absolute. When I try to remove the border, all the shapes get skewed and pile up in the middle.

Any idea about how to fix this?

Currently, this is the HTML:

```
<body>


<!--Begin Image-->



 <!--Invisible Box-->

  <div class="box">
<!--Begin Head-->
<div class="head">
  <!--Begin Eyeballs ~ Yellow-->
  <div class="right-eye">
    <div class="pupil"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-eye">
    <div class="pupil"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Begin Beak-->
  <div class="beak"></div>
  <!--Begin Face Shadows-->
  <div class="right-shadow"></div>
  <div class="left-shadow"></div> 
</div>
<!--Begin Body-->
<div class="body">
  <!--Begin Wings-->
  <div class="right-wing"></div>
  <div class="left-wing"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
body {
background: #3E5C76; 
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 420px;
  border: solid white 3px; 
}

.head{
  position: absolute;
  height: 27%; 
  width: 30%; 
  margin-top: 8%; 
  margin-left: 35%; 
  background: #F1F3F0; 
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0; 
}

.left-eye {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%; 
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%; 
  background: #F7D871; 
  margin-top: 10%; 
  margin-left: 20%; 
}

.right-eye{
  position: absolute; 
  height: 30%; 
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%; 
  margin-left: 52%;
  margin-top: 10%; 
  background: #F7D871; 
}

.pupil{
  position: absolute; 
  height: 92%; 
  width: 65%; 
  background: black; 
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%; 
  margin-top: 1%; 
  margin-left: 18%; 
}

.beak{
  position: absolute; 
  height: 20%; 
  width: 10%; 
  background: #CE6644;
  margin-top: 20%; 
  margin-left: 44%;
  background: #3F3F3F; 
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%); 
}

.body{
  position: relative; 
  height: 37%; 
  width: 30%; 
  background: white; 
  margin: auto; 
  margin-top: 26%;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another answer points out, your positioning relies on that border. One workaround is to change the color of the border with transparent as your color of choice.

```
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements that are absolutely positioned are removed from the DOM flow, no other element knows that the absolute element exists.

When you remove the border, all the elements lose reference to where they should be laid out on the page. The elements will all clump together because they don't know how to lay themselves out relative to each other, only relative to their closest `position: relative` parent.